# Send sms to recipients iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, sms

I want to send an SMS via iPhone code to a selected recipient - I don't want to have to specify the recipient's number in the code. I want the app to take the message and enable me to select recipients from the Contacts in the iPhone device.

Comment: you didn't got my mean, I want the app opens the contacts and let me select the recipient, not write it in the code like what is shown in links that you sent

Answer (score 0):

For sending an SMS you only option is [`MFMessageComposeViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) which allows you to prefill it and then present it to the user.

You are not able to send SMS via code, since this could be misused to send messages to service  number which could cost the user momey.